# Can I ask same question in multiple sites?

Tags: discussion, support, cross-posting

Can I ask same question in both *stackoverflow.com* and *programmers.stackexchange.com* or maybe other Stack Exchange site? or it will be duplicate question?

Comment: related: [What difficulties could be there in establishing automatic checks for SO cross-posts on a site like our (50-100 questions a day)?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6660/31260)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [the official guidance for cross-posting questions between Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). In short, each site is a different community. Even if the question would be on-topic on multiple sites, you should read each site's Help Center to find out what is and isn't on-topic and similar questions to find out the types of answers each site provides, and then ask the question where you feel you'll get the best answers. If you aren't getting the answers you need, moderators can migrate it if it's necessary. Alternatively, you can always ask a new question on a new site that is worded differently to get better answers. However, simply copy and pasting questions between sites isn't recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.

Well, technically you can, but it's preferred if you don't.

Posting duplicate questions on multiple sites makes it harder for future users to find the answer to the question.